# Different methods to create exceptions to capitalizing a string

Tags: python

Is there another to have exception for capitalizing an entire sentence. I've heard of skipList method, but it didn't work for my code. See below:

```
string = input('Enter a string: ')

i = 0
tempString = ' '.join(s[0].upper() + s[1:] for s in string.split(' '))
result = ""

for word in tempString.split():

    if i == 0:
        result = result + word + " "
    elif (len(word) <= 2):
        result = result + word.lower() + " "
    elif (word == "And" or word == "The" or word == "Not"):
        result = result + word.lower() + " "
    else:
        result = result + word + " "
    i = i + 1

print ("\n")

print (result)
```

Comment: Copy and format your code instead of an image.

Comment: Edited the format

Comment: N.B. that your `tempString` line is just `tempString = string.title()`.

Comment: The counter `i` is unnecessary if you just initialize `result = word[0] + ' '` and then loop over `tempString.split()[1:]`

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Write a ***complete*** list of words that should not be title-cased ("and", "the", "or", "not", etc), and title-case everything else.

```
words = s.split(' ')

result = ' '.join([words[0]] + [w.title() for w in words[1:] if w not in skipwords])
```

of course this will still miss Mr. Not's last name, which should be capitalized, and some stranger things like `"McFinnigan"` will be wrong, but language is hard. If you want better than that, you'll probably have to look into NTLK.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite this like this

```
skip_words = {w.capitalize(): w for w in 'a in of or to and for the'.split()}
words = string.title().split()
result = ' '.join(skip_words.get(w, w) for w in words).capitalize()
```

Comment: I did it this method and my question is I don't have to mention two letter words and it automatically doesn't capitalize them without being in skip_words, why is that?

Comment: Can you give an example? I'm pretty sure `str.title()` capitalizes every word, regardless of length.